# Updating mysql database using your findings in python

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, sql-update

I am new to python so this might have wrong syntax as well. I want to bulk update my sql database. I have already created a column in the database with null values. My aim is to find the moving average on python then use those value to update the database. But the problem is that the moving averages that I have found is in a data table format where columns are time blocks and rows are dates. But in the database both dates and time blocks are different column.

```
MA30 = pd.rolling_mean(df, 30)

cur.execute(""" UPDATE feeder_ndmc_copy 
            SET time_block = CASE date, (MA30)""")

db.commit()
```

This is the error I am getting.

```
self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)
```

I have seen a lot of other question answers but there is no example of how to use the finding of python command to update the database. Any suggestions?

Comment: What is the exact error you are getting from python? Does this work from the MySQL CLI?

Comment: Please post the error message and the stack trace. What you have posted looks like only a small part of the stack trace. Also your example is not complete. Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve on how to make it easier for people to help you. One thing that strikes me is that you seem to try to insert the variable `MA30` into the SQL query. The way you go about this you tell your SQL API to insert the string MA30. Without knowing the schema of your database though, it's kinda hard to formulate a query for you.

Comment: I don't know how to use Mysql. I am new to this field. @Claris

Comment: And about the error, the thing is I am not quite sure about the query myself. If I had to update only 3 values then I know what is the query.                             UPDATE categories
    SET display_order = CASE id
        WHEN 1 THEN 3
        WHEN 2 THEN 4
        WHEN 3 THEN 5
    END

Comment: But here I don't know how to use my results to update the database.

Comment: Please post the complete error message and the stack trace. What you posted isn't an error message, it is part of a stack trace. An error message would look something like this (depending on the kind of error):  `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`.

Comment: I am telling you that I am not sure about the query because I don't know how to write it but still here is the whole error:                                                     
  line 37, in <module>
    SET time_block = CASE date, (MA30)""")
   line 205, in execute
    self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)
   line 36, in defaulterrorhandler
    raise errorclass, errorvalue
_mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ' (MA30)' at line 2" @sobek

Comment: Was my answer of any help? If it covers your question, you should accept it so people know your question is answered. If it doesn't work for you, please leave a comment so i can adapt my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so it is very hard to give you a complete answer with what little information your question contains, but I'll try my best to explain how I would deal with this.

The easiest way is probably to automatically write a separate `UPDATE` query for each row you want to update. If I'm not mistaken, this will be relatively efficient on the database side of things but it will produce some overhead in your python program. I'm not a database guy, but since you didn't mention performance optimality in your question, i will assume that any solution that works will do for now.

I will be using sqlalchemy to handle interactions with the database. Take care that if you want to copy my code, you will need to install sqlalchemy and import the module in your code.

First, we will need to create a sqlalchemy engine. I will assume that you use a local database, if not you will need to edit this part.

```
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine('mysql://localhost/yourdatabase')
```

Now lets create a string containing all our queries (i don't know the name of the columns you want to update, so I'll use place holders, I also do no know the format of your time index, so I'll have to guess):

```
queries = ''
for index, value in MA30.iterrows():
    queries += 'UPDATE feeder_ndmc_copy SET column_name = {} WHERE index_column_name = {};\n'.format(value, index.strftime(%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S))
```

You will need to adapt this part heavily to conform with your requirements. I simply can't do any better without you supplying the proper schema of your database.

With the list of queries complete, we proceed to put the data into SQL:

```
with engine.connect() as connection:
    with engine.begin():
        connection.execute(queries)
```

**Edit:**

Obviously my solution does not deal in any way with things like if your pandas operations create datapoints for timestamps that are not in mysql, etc. You need to keep that in mind. If that is a problem, you will need to use queries of the form

```
INSERT INTO table (id,Col1,Col2) VALUES (1,1,1),(2,2,3),(3,9,3),(4,10,12)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Col1=VALUES(Col1),Col2=VALUES(Col2);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I think it has helped me a lot to reach the desired result I wanted. Thanks again @sobek